# Android Google Save password prompt is flashing and disappearing

Tags: android, android-keypad, password-manager

I have a login screen, where the user enters the email and password the following screen is an OTP screen.

[image]

The issue is that when a user enters their email and password and moves to the OTP screen the "Save password to Google" prompt shows up for a split second and disappears. I think this is because I am enabling the showing soft keyboard by requesting focus on OTP EditText when I reach the OTP screen.

How can I handle this properly?
Is there any callback that I can listen to for the save password prompt? so that I can show the keyboard after it is dismissed?

Or

Is there a way to control when the save password shows up? Force it to show up before moving to the OTP screen.